# jquery find element by specific class when element has multiple classes

Tags: jquery, class, element

So I am working on something that wasn't well thought out in the build from the backend team. That leaves me with a document full of divs.

What I am doing is rolling back from the element I need to click on, get the parent container then find an element within the parent which has `class="alert-box warn"`, `class="alert-box dead"`, etc... Essentially, I'm trying to use multiple class selectors on each element. When I try to find just `alert-box` it doesn't seem to be working right. I'm assuming because it has `warn,`dead, ``fine, etc...

How can I find just `alert-box*` or equivalent to a wildcard concept?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your HTML markup?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can combine selectors like this

```
$(".alert-box.warn, .alert-box.dead");
```

Or if you want a wildcard use the [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("[class*='alert-box']");
```

Note: Preferably you would know the element type or tag when using the selectors above. Knowing the tag can make the selector more efficient.

```
$("div.alert-box.warn, div.alert-box.dead");
$("div[class*='alert-box']");
```

Comment: I'd recommend the first selector over the latter one.

Comment: You can also substitute the *= for ^= if you are interested in making sure the element's class "begins with" alert-box rather than just "contains" alert-box.

Comment: I just posted an example jsfiddle     https://jsfiddle.net/frxyqzw3/2/    showing the class* idea

Answer (score 11):

You can select elements with multiple classes like so:

```
$("element.firstClass.anotherClass");
```

Simply chain the next class onto the first one, *without* a space (spaces mean "children of").

Answer (score 5):

```
var divs = $("div[class*='alert-box']");
```

Answer (score 3):

An element can have any number of classNames, however, it can only have one class attribute; only the first one will be read by jQuery.

Using the code you posted, `$(".alert-box.warn")` will work but `$(".alert-box.dead")` will not.

Comment: Only the first `class=""` attribute will be read by the browser, let alone jQuery.

Comment: That's the point I meant to get across with this answer, is it not clear enough?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that jQuery won't actually _see_ any further `class=""`es due to the browser's HTML parser ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for  http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

```
<div id="mydiv" class="foo bar"></div>

$('#mydiv').hasClass('foo') //returns ture
```

Comment: No, he's not - he wants to select elements based on which class they have, not to see whether an element he's got has a class or not.