# How to highlight p:tab's with inputfields that contain validation errors

Tags: jsf, primefaces

A large form has several input fields so that they are grouped inside primefaces tabview tabs. Some of these fields are mandatory. When the user tries to submit, it gets the required message, but the user has to scroll through all the tabes to locate the fields missing fields. Is there any way to highlight tabs with missing values?

Comment: Look at the Primefaces [SpotLight](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/spotlight.xhtml) maybe it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally do this client-side.

1. I'd start with checking IF a validation failed in general or not like in the PrimeFaces solution in here:

   - [How to find indication of a Validation error (required="true") while doing ajax command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617914/how-to-find-indication-of-a-validation-error-required-true-while-doing-ajax)
2. In the javascript function that you can call, I'd find the surrounding form via jquery.

   - [jQuery find parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621714/jquery-find-parent-form)
3. And from that form down I'd find via jquery all inputs with a css class that indicate an error.

   - [jquery find element by specific class when element has multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587966/jquery-find-element-by-specific-class-when-element-has-multiple-classes)
4. From each error I'd find the ancestor element that is the tab of the div (this might be where you need to be most creative, but it IS all plain jquery with wich many can help you if you make it a plain jquery question) and add a css class to this so you can style it 'in error'.
5. I'd find, again with jquery, the first tab that has errors and 'fake' a click on it.

   - [find first occurrence of class in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423804/find-first-occurrence-of-class-in-div)
   - [Simulate a click on 'a' element using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569012/simulate-a-click-on-a-element-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: An example can be found on this page: [Primefaces: Displaying Tabs with Validation Errors](http://stickysession.com/2016/03/primefaces-displaying-tabs-with-validation-errors/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do server-side validation. So if a validation error occurred  you know the tab that the error is locate. 
Then you can use the [activetabindex](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/spotlight.xhtml) of `TabView` and activate the tab that you want.

Then you can use `Spotlite` as [@fuggerjak61](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10547108/fuggerjaki61) said to locate the missing/not valid fields.

Comment: I assume the validation is already server side (common practice with JSF). So that makes your second statement _" So if a validation error occurred you know the tab that the error is locate. "_ the main 'problem'... How do you know the tab? How do you retrieve that? And what if you have multiple tags? Than you get the first one, but how do you get to the second?

Comment: I suppose that you know what fields have each tab.

Comment: I used the required attribute to validate. So difficult to validate at server side.